# Remove outlines ContentDialog box

Tags: uwp

I'm using a content dialog and I want to delete the outlines from the dialog and I couldn't find a way to do that any help

Here's my code

```
<ContentDialog
x:Class="app.Pages.SettingDetailsPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:app.Pages"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Name="dialog2"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="880" Height="600" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{x:Null}" IsPrimaryButtonEnabled="False" IsSecondaryButtonEnabled="False" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Content" AutomationProperties.LandmarkType="Navigation" IsTextScaleFactorEnabled="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" AutomationProperties.PositionInSet="0" AutomationProperties.SizeOfSet="0" AutomationProperties.Level="0" AutomationProperties.IsRequiredForForm="True">
<ContentDialog.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform/>
</ContentDialog.RenderTransform>
<ContentDialog.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <ContentThemeTransition/>
    </TransitionCollection>
</ContentDialog.Transitions>
<Grid x:Name="Main" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="853" Height="624" Background="#FF1F1E1E">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="25,-1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="825" Background="{StaticResource BoxBackground}"/>
    <SplitView x:Name="detailpanel"
       OpenPaneLength="240" PaneBackground="{StaticResource NavigationPaneBackground}" Margin="0,-6,3,25" IsPaneOpen="False" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid Background="#FF151515">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" Background="{StaticResource BoxBackground}"/>
                <Button x:Name="button" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Height="48"/>


            </Grid>

        </SplitView.Pane>

    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

[image: outlines]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `<Thickness x:Key="ContentDialogBorderWidth">0</Thickness>` in your App.xaml.